# Safari limitation? Using multiple methods in order to show multiple custom modal dialogs

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari

I have tried multiple methods in order to show multiple modal dialogues in order prior to finishing processing on the original screen.  The modal dialogues would all be kicked off after a form is submitted.  They should open in order, because the first modal has info that the second modal needs and so on.  All methods I have attempted (with the simplified versions below for now) work fine in IE (and in Mozilla as well), but when I try to test them in Safari they do not work the way I want them to.  Here is really the simplified/stipped down verion of what I'm really going for.  I basically want to make sure the test.html page loads before the alert goes off.  In IE this works the way I would expect it to for both methods below - load the page in the modalcontent div, then show the alert.  In firefox, it shows the alert first then the screen changes/reloads.  I've tried using the javascript methods setInterval and setTimeout, but in firefox the alert still shows up before the screen refresh.  Any idea if there's something I'm missing?  Am I approaching this all wrong?

```
<TABLE><TR>
<TD ALIGN="center" bgcolor="red" onClick="showNonIEModal('test.html');
alert('alert to show up AFTER load');">CLICK ME</TD>
</TR></TABLE>

<div id="modalcontent"></div>
```

Ajax method:

```
<SCRIPT>function showNonIEModal(url)
{
var dsp;
var element = document.getElementById("modalcontent"); 
element.innerHTML = '<p><em>Loading ...</em></p>'; 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    dsp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    dsp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

dsp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (dsp.readyState==4 && dsp.status==200){
        element.innerHTML=dsp.responseText;
    }
}
dsp.open("GET",url,true);
dsp.send();
}</SCRIPT>
```

second method:

```
<SCRIPT>function showNonIEModal(url)
{
var element = document.getElementById("modalcontent"); 
element.innerHTML='<'+'iframe id="'+frameName+'" name="'+frameName+'" src="'+url+'" 
FRAMEBORDER="0" height="500px" width= "600px"><\/iframe>';
}</SCRIPT>
```

Any ideas?  I have spent countless hours on this issue.  It seems like this is an issue with Safari.  In searching for an answer I have found a lot of responses regarding using JQuery, but that is not an option for me.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little fuzzy on what exactly the order of expected results is, but I think it's:

1. Click "CLICK ME"
2. Expect modalcontent div's content to change
3. Show alert.

If this is correct, here's the problem (I think). You're relying on an ajax request (i.e. something non-synchronous) to complete before running the next line of code. I know IE is working for you, but IE isn't much to go by. What you want is probably something more like this:

```
<SCRIPT>function showNonIEModal(url, callback)
{
var dsp;
var element = document.getElementById("modalcontent"); 
element.innerHTML = '<p><em>Loading ...</em></p>'; 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    dsp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    dsp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

dsp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (dsp.readyState==4 && dsp.status==200){
        element.innerHTML=dsp.responseText;
        callback && callback(); //This is the part I changed
    }
}
dsp.open("GET",url,true);
dsp.send();
}</SCRIPT>
```

Now, when you want to run it..

```
<TABLE><TR>
<TD ALIGN="center" bgcolor="red" onClick="showNonIEModal('test.html', function () {alert('alert to show up AFTER load')});">CLICK ME</TD>
</TR></TABLE>

<div id="modalcontent"></div>
```

This will force that alert to wait until the content has been received from the server and processed. Pretty common asynchronous pattern - do X, and then when you're done, run this function which will continue with Y and Z.

Comment: Thank you for the response, you understood the order of expected results correctly. Unfortunately I tried this in safari to no avail, it still loads the alert then the page is refreshed.